# How to show items of lazylist out of the Card in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll, android-jetpack-compose, lazylist

I have LazyRow in a Card and I want scrolling items to come outside the card,
could you please guide me, how can I do that?

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to display something on top of `Card`, you can use `Box`. You can calculate the needed padding for it to match the card. Think of `Card` as just a background view in this case.

```kotlin
val outerPadding = 20.dp
val innerPadding = 20.dp
Box {
    Card(
        backgroundColor = Color.White,
        elevation = 10.dp,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(outerPadding).aspectRatio(1f).fillMaxWidth()
    ) {

    }
    Column(
        Modifier
            .matchParentSize()
            .padding(vertical = outerPadding + innerPadding)
    ) {
        Text(
            "Your title",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = outerPadding + innerPadding)
        )
        HorizontalPager(
            count = 10,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = outerPadding + innerPadding),
            itemSpacing = innerPadding / 2,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        ) {
            Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Green))
        }
        Text(
            "Your indicator",
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = outerPadding + innerPadding)
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this way doesn't work for my scenario, in the screenshots I have a header inside the card as well. I want just the slider comes on top of the card!

Comment: I have also a DotIndicator component under the slider which should be inside the card and under slider, this order -> 1- header , 2- slider, 3- dotIndicator

Comment: Do you know that is there anyway that it works without aspectRatio or static height ? I want to fill the height according to the data
@Pylyp Dukhov ,

Comment: @SepidehVatankhah you need to duplicate content of once cell inside your `Card`, so it can measure the size.

Comment: It didn't work for me, it duplicates the datas ... I don't have only a green card, it has data inside

Comment: @SepidehVatankhah make it invisible with `Modifier.alpha(0)`